# How to call a function of a widget using a slot?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, signals-slots

Consider following `main.cpp` (the only file of the whole Qt-project):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QObject>
#pragma once

class collectedFunctions : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    collectedFunctions(QObject* parent = 0) {};
    ~collectedFunctions() {};

public slots:
    void setFunc() {
        //Calculate 2+2 and change text of the label accordingly
    }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;
    window.resize(200, 200);
    window.setWindowTitle("Test-GUI");
    QVBoxLayout layout(&window);

    QPushButton button(&window);
    button.setText("Test");
    button.show();
    
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(&window);
    label->setText("Hello");

    collectedFunctions testingFuncs;

    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &testingFuncs, &collectedFunctions::setFunc);
    
    layout.addWidget(&button);
    layout.addWidget(label);
    
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

My goal with this code is to create a slot that runs a function which the programmer defines (similar to the pyqt-implementation of the signals and slots system).

The code above successfully compiles, not throwing any errors and so far meeting my expectations.

Yet as soon I want to manipulate a widget (which in this case is the label), the `setfunc`-slot does not find the defined label.

How can I manipulate a widget using this slot (e.g. using `setText()` at a label or `addItems()` at a combobox) or generally have them being recognized in the slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you shouldn't use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in **main.cpp**.

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class
> definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other
> services provided by Qt's meta-object system.
>
> The moc tool reads a C++ **header** file. If it finds one or more class
> declarations that contain the **Q_OBJECT macro**, it produces a C++ source
> file containing the meta-object code for those classes. Among other
> things, meta-object code is required for the signals and slots
> mechanism, the run-time type information, and the dynamic property
> system.
>
> The C++ source file generated by moc must be compiled and linked with
> the implementation of the class.

When you have your class defined in `.cpp` file instead of `.h` file moc **fails** to process it properly.

**you need a separate file for class:**

**in collectedfunctions.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

class collectedFunctions: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    collectedFunctions(QObject *parent = 0);

    ~collectedFunctions();

public slots:
    void  setFunc();
};
```

**and in collectedfunctions.cpp**

```
#include "collectedfunctions.h"
#include <QDebug>

collectedFunctions::collectedFunctions(QObject *parent)
{
}

collectedFunctions::~collectedFunctions()
{
}

void  collectedFunctions::setFunc()
{
    qDebug() << "2+2 = " << 2 + 2;
}
```

**and in your main.cpp**

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QWidget>
 #include <QPushButton>
 #include <QVBoxLayout>
 #include <QLabel>

#include "collectedfunctions.h"

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  app(argc, argv);
    QWidget       window;

    window.resize(200, 200);
    window.setWindowTitle("Test-GUI");
    QVBoxLayout  layout(&window);
    QPushButton  button(&window);
    button.setText("Test");
    button.show();

    QLabel *label = new QLabel(&window);
    label->setText("Hello");

    collectedFunctions  testingFuncs;

    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &testingFuncs, &collectedFunctions::setFunc);

    layout.addWidget(&button);
    layout.addWidget(label);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

don't forget to add `QT +=core gui widgets` in your `.pro` file.

**Result:**

[image]

#### If you want to change QLabel Text :

**in collectedfunctions.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

class collectedFunctions: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit collectedFunctions(QObject *parent = 0);

    ~collectedFunctions();

signals:
    void  updateLable(int num);

public slots:
    void  setFunc();

private:
    int  num = 0;
};
```

**and in collectedfunctions.cpp**

```
#include "collectedfunctions.h"
#include <QDebug>

collectedFunctions::collectedFunctions(QObject *parent)
{
}

collectedFunctions::~collectedFunctions()
{
}

void  collectedFunctions::setFunc()
{
    qDebug() << "2+2 = " << 2 + 2;

    num++;
    emit  updateLable(num);
}
```

**and in your main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

#include "collectedfunctions.h"

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  app(argc, argv);
    QWidget       window;

    window.resize(200, 200);
    window.setWindowTitle("Test-GUI");
    QVBoxLayout  layout(&window);
    QPushButton  button(&window);
    button.setText("Test");
    button.show();

    QLabel *label = new QLabel(&window);
    label->setText("Hello");

    collectedFunctions  testingFuncs;

    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &testingFuncs, &collectedFunctions::setFunc);

    QObject::connect(&testingFuncs, &collectedFunctions::updateLable, [&label](int num)
    {
        qDebug() << "Number = " << num;
        label->setText(QString::number(num));
    });

    layout.addWidget(&button);
    layout.addWidget(label);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**you can see:**

[image]

Comment: Re. `"you can't use the Q_OBJECT macro in main.cpp."`: sorry, but that's simply wrong.  `moc` can be used to process any valid `c++` code.  Whether or not `qmake` allows that is another story (I don't use `qmake`).

Comment: @G.M. I think this issue will happen if you use `Cmake`,as I know we should define class which use `Q_OBJECT macro` in other files and in a`.h`  part of class. I try to fixed his/her code and I will be happy if you say other better answer.

Comment: Whether or not `qmake` or `cmake` can run `moc` on non-headers is irrelevant here.  My point is that `moc` itself can be run on (almost) any valid `c++` code.  It's perfectly possible to write an entire `Qt` application in a single `.cpp` file containing `moc`'able classes that make use of `Q_OBJECT` etc. -- no need for any additional headers.

Comment: @G.M. please try ```#include <QObject> class A: public QObject{ Q_OBJECT public: A(QObject *parent = 0){}  public slots:  void  setFunc(); }; int main(){ 
  
A *a = new A;  return 0;}
```
In **main.cpp**  it didn't work.

Comment: @G.M. How could we use `Q_OBJECT` in `main.cpp` ? means that `-- no need for any additional headers`.

Comment: The code in your comment works fine with my own makefiles and `moc` (after I provide a definition for `A::setFunc`).  My point is that the problems you are attributing to `moc` are actually issues with the higher level build tools such as `qmake` etc.: `moc` itself doesn't care whether it's processing a header file or a source file or whatever.  But none of this is helping the OP so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

From Qt Documentation [QObject::connect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#connect-4)

> ### template <typename PointerToMemberFunction, typename Functor>
> QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender,
> PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor)
>
> This function overloads connect().
>
> Creates a connection from signal in sender object to functor, and
> returns a handle to the connection
>
> The signal must be a function declared as a signal in the header. The
> slot function can be any function or functor that can be connected to
> the signal. A slot function can be connected to a given signal if the
> signal has at least as many arguments as the slot function. There must
> exist implicit conversion between the types of the corresponding
> arguments in the signal and the slot.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> void someFunction();
> QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
> QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, someFunction);
> ```